# R - Saving xlsx: Include data and time in file name

Tags: r, date, export, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to export a dataset as an xlsx and would like it to show date and time of creation in the name. When I do the following, it works fine, but does not show the time:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, 
         file = paste('/Path/Path/Path/Data Output ',
                      Sys.Date(),
                      '.xlsx', 
                      sep = ""),
         overwrite = TRUE)
```

However, if I add Sys.time() like below, it just doesn't save anything anymore.

```
    saveWorkbook(wb, 
             file = paste('/Path/Path/Path/Data Output ',
                          Sys.Date(),
                          Sys.time(),
                          '.xlsx', 
                          sep = ""),
             overwrite = TRUE)
```

What do I need to do to get DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM or anything containing all these pieces of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")`

```
saveWorkbook(wb, 
             file = paste('/Path/Path/Path/Data Output ',
                          format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"),
                          '.xlsx', 
                          sep = ""),
             overwrite = TRUE)
```